# I can't upgrade 13.10 because of broken pipe

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, pipe

I try upgrading and this is what I get:

```
christopher@chris-computer:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for christopher: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  librhythmbox-core7
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/809 kB of archives.
After this operation, 39.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 170617 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace librhythmbox-core7 2.99.1-0ubuntu1 (using .../librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement librhythmbox-core7 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0', which is also in package librhythmbox-core8 3.0.1-1ubuntu2~ppa0
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are downloading the package `librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_i386.deb` when you already have `librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0` installed. Probably a PPA issue.

My suggestion is to remove all `librhythmbox` packages and reinstall your preferred version.

1. Remove the current `librhythmbox` installation with `sudo dpkg --remove librhythmbox-core`
2. Update your apt cache with `sudo apt-get update`
3. Reinstall `librhythmbox` with `sudo apt-get install -f librhythmbox`